# SVN GIT respository server

Tags: git, svn

Our entire code is stored in a SVN respository on a remote server. However, my team here is in favor of using GIT local server by cloning svn repository using git-svn. The problem I face is how do I make sure that my local team members are able to clone the git-svn local repository and each "push" to local git-svn repository is published to SVN repository. I think I can run a cron job to rebase the git-svn repository with SVN repository every 20 or 30 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add post-receive hook to commit pushed changes to svn.